# Difference in Eclipse Mars and Eclipse MARS PHP instance

Tags: php, eclipse

I have Eclipse Mars installed and I wish to try some PHP. I know there is a PHP add on for Eclipse in the Market place but also have found what appears to be a specific Eclipse for PHP instance that can be downloaded from the Eclipse website.  My question is should I install the PHP plugin to my current Eclipse Mars install or install the specific Eclipse for PHP instance?

Comment: It makes no difference, you end up with the same thing if you install the same plugins that the pre-built version contains.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for prompt response.  So the specific Eclipse for PHP is just eclipse with the PHP plugin already set up in the instance?  Is Eclipse good for creating PHP?

Comment: Yes, the various builds on the Eclipse site are just the core Eclipse plus appropriate plugins for different uses. I don't use PHP so I can't say how good it is.